# Multibib: How to start a reference counter from a specific number?

Tags: bibtex, article, multibib

I am using the `multibib` package and would like to start the numbering from a specific number such as 10 instead of the default 1. How to achieve that for the `article` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
   \oldthebibliography{#1}%
   \setcounter{enumiv}{10}%
}
```